# Enmascarar STRING con simbolos

Tags: java, kotlin

Hola compañeros existe alguna manera de enmascarar un String de la siguiente manera?

La cadena sería:
"Mi negocio SA de CV"

la cadena deseada a obtener es la siguiente:

"M* N***** S* d* C*"

He buscado pero solo encuentro la manera de enmascarar la cadena así

"M**************"

Muchas gracias por su ayuda y comprensión.

```
fun convertStr(cadena: String): String {
    var finalString = ""
    if (cadena.isNotEmpty()) {
        finalString += cadena.substring(0, 1)
        for (i in 1 until cadena.length) {
            finalString += "*"
        }
    } else {
        finalString = ""
    }
    return finalString
}
```

Comment: O sea solamente quieres que este visible la primera letra de cada palabra?

Comment: asi es, solo la primera letra de cada palabra

Comment: Y por otra parte edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo que tienes

Comment: Listo está editado

Comment: En que lenguaje Kotlin o Java?

Comment: esta en kotlin pero cualquiera de los dos está bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Código para **Java**:

```
String EnmascararTexto(String texto)
{
   String textoFinal = ""; 
   String p = "";

   if(texto.isEmpty() == false)
   {
      String[] palabras = texto.split(" ");

      for(int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++)
      {
         p = palabras[i];
         textoFinal += p.charAt(0); 

         for(int j = 1; j < p.length(); j++)
         {
            textoFinal += "*";
         }

         textoFinal += " ";
      }
   }

   return textoFinal.trim();
}
```

Se crea la **función** **EnmascararTexto** que devuelve un **String** y recibe como parámetro un **String** que es el texto original a enmascarar.

Dentro de la función se pregunta si el parámetro pasado no está vacío, de no estarlo se llama a la **función** **split**, la cual devuelve un **arreglo de string** donde cada posición de ese arreglo es una palabra del texto original, la **función** **split** recibe como parámetro un **caracter delimitador** para separar ese texto, en este caso el caracter delimitador es un espacio(" "). Este nuevo arreglo se guarda en la **variable palabras**

Posteriormente se hace un **ciclo for** que va a recorrer cada palabra guardada en el **arreglo palabras** y por cada palabra se va a coger la primera letra, la cual no se enmascara y además se hará otro **ciclo for** para recorrer el resto de las letras de esa palabra que si se enmascaran.

Por último se devuelve el texto ya enmascarado.

Comment: gracias me ha funcionado correctamente

Answer (score 2):

## Solución 1

Creo que esta solución puede ser una de las mejores, pues usa [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) para detectar un patrón y remplazarlo con el token deseado.

Para ello de la clase **String** utilizamos el método [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), con la siguiente regex: `\B[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]`

Recordemos que:

- **\B** es la negación de **\b** el cuál busca un *word boundary* (un límite de palabras)
- **[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]** son todas las letras del alfabeto español

**Código**

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(change(" Hola  de SA de CV      "));
    }

    private static String change(String msg) {
        if(msg.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        msg = msg
                .trim()
                .replaceAll(" {2,}", " ")
                .replaceAll("\\B[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]", "*")
                .toUpperCase();

        return msg;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
H*** D* S* D* C*
```

## Solución 2

El algoritmo propuesto es lineal y utilizará una variable booleana que le indicará si está en modo de reemplazo.

**Algoritmo**

- Verificaremos que la cadena no esté vacía, de ser así, retornaremos `null`
- Eliminaremos los espacios de sobra con `trim()` y `replaceAll()`
- Dejamos la primera letra tal como está y empezamos a iterar desde el segundo carácter. Para ello iniciamos en modo de remplazo.

  - Si la letra en el índice es un espacio, quitamos el modo de reemplazo, agregamos ese espacio y continuamos a la siguiente iteración
  - Si estamos en modo de reemplazo, agregamos un asterisco, de lo contrario agregamos la letra.
- Retornamos la cadena en mayúsculas.

**Código**

```java
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(change("Hola de SA de CV"));
    }

    private static String change(String msg) {
        if(msg.isEmpty()){
            return null;
        }
        msg = msg.trim().replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(msg.length());
        str.append(msg.charAt(0));
        boolean replacement = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < msg.length(); ++i){
            if (msg.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                replacement = false;
                str.append(' ');
                continue;
            }

            str.append(replacement ? '*' : msg.charAt(i));
            replacement = true;
        }

        return str.toString().toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

**Notas:**

1. Para mejorar la construcción de nuestra cadena hacemos uso de la clase [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
2. Esta misma clase se inicializa con la longitud de la cadena para mejorar el performance

**Output**

```
H*** D* S* D* C*
```

Answer (score 2):

Todas las repuestas son correctas pero quiero agegar un ejemplo en kotlin porque  se puede hacer de una manera más sencilla. Kotlin tiene una función llamada `joinToString` que convierte una lista en `String` y puede aplicar una transformación a cada elemento. Entonces una solución es separar el texto en palabras usando `split(" ")` y luego unirlo con `joinToString(" ")`

```
fun convertStr(cadena: String) = cadena.split(" ").joinToString(" ") {
    if (it.length < 2) it
    else it[0] + CharArray(it.length - 1) { '*' }.concatToString()
}
```

El argumento `" "` es para que lo use como delimitador entre las palabras. La ventaja es que no añade un espacio extra al final por lo que no necesitarás usar `trim()`. Otra ventaja es que internamente usa un `StringBuilder` lo que la hace muy eficiente sin que tengas que agregar código extra.

En la función de transformación concateno la primera letra de la palabra con una string que contiene un caracter `*` por cada letra restante en la palabra.